# How can I get the upload progress when uploading to Google Drive with driveApi.files.create

Tags: flutter, dart, google-drive-api

How can I get the upload progress?

```
var driveApi = ga.DriveApi(client);
var fileToUpload = File(sfilePath + sfileName + '.jpg');
var response = await driveApi.files.create(ga.File()..name = 'my_file.jpg',
     uploadMedia: ga.Media(fileToUpload.openRead(), fileToUpload.lengthSync()));
print(response.toJson());
```

Even on stackoverflows existing questions there is only this example but never with the progress for uploading. Have anybody an idea, please?

Comment: see once :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCmAwk2fnZc

Comment: Calculate the length left based upon the total length?

Comment: @DaImTo can you please submit an example? I dont get it.

Comment: No sorry i dont dart, and SO doesnt submit examples really you should give it a try edit your question and show any errors if you have any issues.   Im sure someone can help once we see what you have attempted.